# Why my keyboard's control are slow?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I'm trying to move my character faster, you can try it here : [whiteplay](http://www.whiteplay.fr/rpg).

To move my Hero, that's my code : (keymaster Library)

```
key('s,down',  function(){ seDeplacer(0,-1); });
key('q,left',  function(){ seDeplacer(1,0);  });
key('z,up',    function(){ seDeplacer(0,1);  });
key('d,right', function(){ seDeplacer(-1,0); });
```

I tried the classic method with the `e.keycode` but it don't change anything.

The problem isn't the way it's laging when I move down for example, but try to move down 2 or 3 cases, and very fast try to move right, don't you see the time between the way you move down, and the way you move right. That's want to reduce to 0

Any Idea

Comment: could you elaborate more on what you problem is? i experience the initial lag that you said you don't' want to change but other than that everything seemed to move the same

Comment: Thank you for your help, imagine that you want to move, you are moving up for example, and in full middle of your displacement up, you decided to go right. The time it will have between the change of direction, the character does not move for half a second, I would like that the character does not lock.